# Any Blog Interest for MVM&R

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have seen other SE sites with Blogs and was wondering if we could (should) have one setup for MVM&R. I know that @BobCross is a prolific sort of person, but don't know if he has time. I myself can (and have) thrown down some writs here and on other forums. I would have no problem of writing a blog entry at least once a month on things which seem important to me concerning MVM&R. I'm thinking technical blogs about how different mechanical things work would be a good start. Mind you "technical" does not need to be synonymous with "boring". One can write and describe things without the worry of being boring.

So, there are two pending questions here:

1. Is there any interest?
2. If there is, what would people want in the blog? (ie: subjects, coverage, etc.)

Here is the community [blog.overflow site](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) for reference.

Looking forward to hearing the community at large.

Comment: In terms of the broader picture - does a blog draw MORE traffic to MVM&R, or if a post is more interesting/detailed than an individual question, end up detracting from it? Or, is it neutral in effect?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling ... If you look at the question which was put up yesterday (was it??) about the difference between a V10 and V12 ... this is something I could pontificate on for two or three pages, talking about not only the differences, but many other things. When it comes down to it though, it *really* isn't on-topic for the Q/A of SE. This is the type of thing which could bring people onto the site, IMHO.

Comment: Ah, ok.. Yes, I did see that question. I guess what you're saying is that you don't see how it could possibly hurt, given that the material you'd be blogging about wouldn't be something that you'd have otherwise posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes!  I was making noise about how fun this would be quite a while back. Two things that would be most fun / valuable:

1. Extended discussion of answers. A blog allows us to talk way outside the strict q&a format. Plus pictures!
2. General nonsense. I would have happily assembled the exhaust manifold, socket wrench and extensions just to show "be careful guys, stuff like this can fall in your face all at once. And it will sting."  ;-)

Comment: What was the consensus when you were making noise before (what was said ... obviously we don't have a blog right now)? Do you have a link to a question of the same (I couldn't find one)? I like it for the reasons you stated as well.

Comment: The reaction was deafening apathy.

Comment: Well, we should wake the place up then ... :D

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Bob - I think it'd be particularly useful for those questions (or variations thereof) that keep coming up time and time again, and for the more generic stuff that doesn't fit the usual Q&A format