# Mechanics.SE Blog?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious as to what everyone would think about starting a blog for the site?

Please post up:

- If you'd be interested in contributing

  - What your activity level would be (how many posts per month/year/ever)
- What content could be brought to a blog?
- Would it really help anyone/anything?
- What would be the format for the blog?
- Any other pertinent ideas about a blog?

Full disclosure, I posted [this Meta post](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1311/4152) nearly two years ago asking the same question. There was a little bit of a response, and I assume those two individuals would be of the same opinion. The difference now from then is Stack Exchange is no longer hosting the blogs. If we would like to create one *somewhere*, we are free to do that, then we can have the Powers-That-Be make the connection for us.

Let me know what you think and where this might go.

**EDIT:** I just found out "The Powers That Be" (namely Stack Exchange) aren't going to link from the site. This isn't a big deal overall, as any blog can be advertised from Meta. Just updating.

Comment: Do they cover the MRC of a blog for the site or is that cost on the collective?

Comment: `MRC` = "Monthly Recurring Cost" (cost of hosting, the domain and the theme)

Comment: Called gasoverflow? ;-) ;-) ;o)

Comment: @anonymous2 I think that's when you eat too many spicy bean burritos ;-)

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea.  Another question is who would be allowed to contribute.  Would it be open to anybody who happens to drop by, or would it take a minimum reputation to participate?  Or yet again, would it only be manually authorized users who could post on it?

Comment: @anonymous2 - IMHO, I think anyone should be able to contribute, but I think there'd need to be some sort of litmus to keep out the stupid riff-raff crap which seems to pop on blogs. Just my thinking, though.

Answer (score 4):

**N.B.** I'm a nobody.  These are just my thoughts.  Don't listen to me.  Listen to someone smarter.

## Interest in Contributing

I have (a little) experience hosting Wordpress blogs on WPEngine.  I also have a bit more experience setting up domain names for blogs, wikis, email, etc.  I would definitely be willing to *advise* on how to set it up, but I have to warn that I should not be *relied on* to set it up; my life is less than predictable.

I am not knowledgeable enough to contribute posts about engines, but if someone wanted it, I can write *extremely* detailed instructions on how to use a tool. (`The Idiot's Guide to This Tool`)

## Content

I would be interested in seeing posts analyzing different types of tools (not brands) including details such as: which is easier to use in which situation, which produces a better result. Brake flaring tools would be a good one.

I would also be interested in seeing posts analyzing different techniques.

## Would It Help

It might not help a specific user, but we're in the business of sharing information.

I think it would encourage authors to really hone the post because they won't be worried about getting their answer in first or moving on to their next answer.

It could give authors a more formal platform to share in-depth knowledge that may just be languishing as an answer to a poorly translated question about a '92 Corolla.  Some people really do put a lot of work into their answers and then only get a few upvotes due to a bad question.  We could harness that energy into a fantastic blog post.

## Format

A blog...

## Other Ideas

#### Content

- Who would be in charge of managing the contributors and setting deadlines?
- How would they enforce deadlines?
- Would we want to keep it to mostly-professional methods or would we allow techniques from "Backwoods John" using a 4x4 block of wood, a winch, and some vegetable oil?

#### Logistics

- Are we willing to spend any money on it *right now*?
- Are we willing to spend any money on it *in the future*?
- Where would that money come from?
- If we stop contributing to it, will whoever is paying for the hosting stop paying so then all of the hard work is lost?
- Who would administer it?
- Who would maintain security?
- Who would be the owner of the domain?
- Who would be the leasee of the server?
- Who would have administrator access to the server?
- Who will have the backups in case of a rogue administrator?
- In the worst case, who would decide that the blog failed?

#### User Experience

- How would we decide the website theme?
- Would comments be allowed?
- Who can comment?
- How do we register commenters?
- What will the license on the posts be?

Comment: What? Your first line is killing me! YOU, sir, aren't a "nobody"! I appreciate your opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd assume we do this in any other way than through a free domain/blogging service such as [Medium.com](https://medium.com/) or [Wordpress.com](https://wordpress.com/)? If worse came to worst, I could add a new WP blog off of my personal site ... not optimal for long term, but it would work.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 You need to purchase a Wordpress.com monthly plan in order to use a [custom domain.](https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/)  We could just use a `[our name].wordpress.com` domain for free on the free plan.  I think there are two questions here: What specific cost are we willing to incur? **If we need to spend money (now or in the future), where would we get the money?** All of this is relevant, but *I believe that producing quality content is 1000x more important than the URL.*

Comment: Agreed on the content. I don't know why a WP or Medium domain name wouldn't work just fine for now and the future. I'd be looking at all things in the "no cost" arena.

Comment: That would be a an awesome thing to do. I'm a web developer and worked in IT security for quite some time. A program like WP is already locked down anyway. You'd just need someone who's familiar with logistics and management.I'd be willing to contribute when I can.